# "cleaning in abortwrite for socket 3" error while publishing data to HiveMQ Server

Tags: sockets, mqtt, paho, broker, hivemq

I have two seperate machines one of them setup as publisher client and the other as HiveMQ broker server. When i am executing my publisher code (which publishes data to HiveMQ Broker), it is aborting with error "cleaning in abortwrite for socket 3". I don't know what wrong i am doing and how this issue can be resolved.

Comment: You need to supply a LOT more information before anybody can help here. Please read the doc about how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask